# Get X,Y Coordinates and pass the value when the icon is clicked (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, position

I want to get the X,Y value of the current mouse pointer and pass other parameters to the javascript function.

[image]

Here is my html code

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info HelpIcon" onclick="OpenHelp(e, 100,200,'My Message');" ></span>
```

Here is my javascript function

```
function OpenHelp(e, h, w, msg) {
                console.log(e.pageX);
                console.log(msg);

                //do something with these values

            }
```

When I run the web page, I am getting that "e" is undefined error.

So, I tried to remove inline 'onclick' code and use the JQuery Click event binding as below:

```
$(".HelpIcon").click(function (e, h, w, msg) {
                    OpenHelp(e, h, w, msg);
                });
```

When I run it, I get the value 'e' but I don't know how to pass the parameters (h, w, msg).

Could you please suggest me?  Thanks.

Comment: what you want to pass through the e? I guess e is event!

Comment: Yes, e is event.  I want to get x,y values of the click

Comment: Just a note: There's no reason to wrap your OpenHelp in an anonymous function like that, just do: $(".HelpIcon").click(OpenHelp). Though I understand you might have done it because you hoped the arguments would follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use non-inline binding and `data-` attributes:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info HelpIcon" data-height="100" data-width="200" data-message="My Message"></span>
```

---

```
$(".HelpIcon").click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    OpenHelp(e, $this.data('height'), $this.data('width'), $this.data('message'));
});
```